# Exception thrown in ordered linked list(write access violation)

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, linked-list

I am getting a write access violation exception when I try to run my code.

```
int main()
{
    OrderedList<int> l;

    l.insert(3);
    l.insert(6);
    l.insert(56);
    l.insert(1);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is OrderedList.h including all the functions of OrderedList class:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class LessComp = less<T>, class Equal = equal_to<T> >
class OrderedList 
{
    private:
        struct Node 
        {
            T value;
            Node* next;
            Node(const T& value, Node* next = nullptr) : value(value), next(next) {}
        };

        Node* first;
        int numElements;

    public:
        OrderedList();
        ~OrderedList();
        bool isEmpty();
        void insert(const T&);
        void remove(const T&);
        int size() const;
        bool find(const T&) const;
        void listItems(ostream&);
};

template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::OrderedList() 
{
    this->first = nullptr;
    this->numElements = 0;
}
template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::~OrderedList()
{
    Node* current = this->first;
    Node* next;

    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }

    this->numElements = 0;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
bool OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::isEmpty()
{
    return this->numElements > 0;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
void OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::insert(const T& element)
{
    Node* temp = this->first;
    Node* node=nullptr;

    LessComp lesscomp;

    if (this->first == nullptr)
    {
        this->first->value=element;
        this->first->next = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        if (lesscomp(element, this->first->value))
        {
            node->value = element;
            node->next = this->first;
            this->first = node;
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp->next != nullptr && !(lesscomp(element, temp->value) && element >= temp->value))
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            if (temp->next == nullptr)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                temp->value = element;
                temp->next = nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
                node->value = element;
                node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = node;
            }
        }
    }

    ++this->numElements;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
void OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::remove(const T& element) 
{
    Node* temp = this->first;
    Node* prev;

    if (temp == nullptr && temp->value == element)
    {
        this->first = temp->next;

        delete temp;

        return;
    }

    while (temp != nullptr && temp->value != element)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    prev->next = temp->next;

    delete temp;

    --this->numElements;
}


template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
int OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::size() const
{
    return this->numElements;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
bool OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::find(const T& element) const
{
    Node* current = this->first;

    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        if (current->value == element)
        {
            return true;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }

    return false;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class Equal >
void OrderedList<T, LessComp, Equal>::listItems(ostream& os)
{
    Node* temp = this->first;

    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        os << temp->value << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

And the error:
[image]

I don't know what to try to solve this problem.

I want to create a sorted linked list using templates.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to step through your code, **line-by-line**, with a debugger, while investigating the values of all of the variables, at **each** execution step, while seeing where it stops matching your expectations? Visual Studio has an excellent debugger.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for your answer! How could I implement insert()function?

Comment: @lambozsolty See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert()` is coded all wrong. When the list is empty, it tries to access the members of `first` when `first` hasn't been allocated yet and is still `nullptr`. In fact, `insert()` doesn't even try to allocate any `Node` instances at all. You need to add calls to `new` inside of `insert()`.

Also, `remove()` is accessing `Node` members via `nullptr` pointers, too.

Also, `isEmpty()` is returning the wrong value, it needs to use `==` instead of `>`.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class LessComp = std::less<T>, class EqualComp = std::equal_to<T> >
class OrderedList 
{
    private:
        struct Node 
        {
            T value;
            Node* next;
            Node(const T& value, Node* next = nullptr) : value(value), next(next) {}
        };

        Node* first = nullptr;
        int numElements = 0;

    public:
        OrderedList() = default;
        OrderedList(const OrderedList&) = delete;
        ~OrderedList();

        bool isEmpty() const;
        void insert(const T&);
        void remove(const T&);
        int size() const;
        bool find(const T&) const;
        void listItems(std::ostream&) const;
};

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::~OrderedList()
{
    Node* current = first;
    Node* next;

    while (current)
    {
        next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }

    numElements = 0;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
bool OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::isEmpty() const
{
    return numElements == 0;
    // or: return first == nullptr;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
void OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::insert(const T& element)
{
    Node* temp = first;
    Node* node = nullptr;

    LessComp lesscomp;

    if (!first)
    {
        first = new Node(element);
    }
    else if (lesscomp(element, first->value))
    {
        first = new Node(element, first);
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp->next && !lesscomp(element, temp->value))
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new Node(element, temp->next);
    }

    ++numElements;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
void OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::remove(const T& element) 
{
    Node* current = first;
    Node** prev = &first;

    EqualComp equalcomp;

    while (current)
    {
        if (equalcomp(current->value, element))
        {
            *prev = current->next;
            delete current;
            --numElements;
            return;
        }

        prev = &(current->next);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
int OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::size() const
{
    return numElements;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
bool OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::find(const T& element) const
{
    Node* current = first;

    EqualComp equalcomp;

    while (current)
    {
        if (equalcomp(current->value, element))
        {
            return true;
        }

        current = current->next;
    }

    return false;
}

template <class T, class LessComp, class EqualComp >
void OrderedList<T, LessComp, EqualComp>::listItems(std::ostream& os) const
{
    Node* temp = first;

    while (temp)
    {
        os << temp->value << std::endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    OrderedList<int> l;

    l.insert(3);
    l.insert(6);
    l.insert(56);
    l.insert(1);

    l.listItems(cout);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/gL1F3J)